# Javascript string search doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to check if a page contains some text. Here is the code that doesn't work, but i am not able to determine why:

```
  var st1 = "Not";
  var st2 = "available";
  var tosearch = str1.concat(str2);
  document.write(tosearch);
  var Availability = "not defined";
  if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(tosearch) > -1){
       Availability = "yes";
  } else {
     Availability = "fdssssssssssssssssssssssss";
  }
```

Comment: What doesnt work? Do you get an error message ?

Comment: You have  `st1` and `st2` but you are using `str1` and `str2` ... was that a typo?

Comment: Because the document.write(tosearch) for example doesn't write enything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not working because you declare `st1` and `st2` but then reference them as `str1` and `str2`. Change to...

```
  var str1 = "Not";
  var str2 = "available";
  var tosearch = str1.concat(str2);
  // The rest of your code...
```

You're also creating the string "Notavailable" which is not what you intend to, I think. Maybe try:

```
  var tosearch = str1 + " " + str2;
```

You could do the same thing with even less code like so:

```
if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf("Not\ available") > -1){
  alert("Yes")
} else {
  alert("No")
}
```

That being said, it's kind of a mystery to me what you're trying to do with this script. :)

Comment: I do like this str1 and str2 because otherwise the script would have foundd itself (the word not available). This is why i split it in 2 parts.

Comment: I am atrying to find if page contains "Not available"

Comment: FYI you could also declare your string as `"Not\ available"` if you want to avoid finding a self-match.

Comment: Thanks. It is much shorter.